# Getting error while adding Test annotation in project using NUnit

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit

I encountered with some errors when tried to add the NUnit Annotation to my code as shown in below image.

[image]

I have done some error research [from Here](https://nunit.org/docs/2.5/exceptionAsserts.html) and [here](https://nunit.org/docs/2.5.7/testFixture.html) also following instructions [from here](http://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-webdriver-csharp-nunit/) too but no success.

Here is the code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ebay_Test_Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            [Test]

        //Instantiate Firefox Driver
        //Go to Ebay Website
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        FirefoxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.ebay.co.uk/");

        Assert.AreEqual("ebay", driver.Title)

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Test` annotation goes outside of the test method. You've placed it inside.

Try this:

```
[Test]
void myTestMethod()
{
    ... your test code here ...
}
```

Also, the `Test` annotation may not work on a `static` method, or on a method with parameters. (I don't remember the details. It's been a while since I used C#.)

I'll bet there's another syntax error on the line that navigates to the Ebay site. If so, try this:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.ebay.co.uk/");
```